# mac osx Database access/crash

Tags: debugging, macos, crash

i have an app that when i run on xcode connects with the database and retrieves the required values PERFECTLY. 
[image]

But when i run the actual application in the Debug folder, it not only does not access the database , it also does not go into any of the functions in my code. 
[image]

Why can an application show this type of behaviour? It never happened before to me. I have an old copy of the code which works fine. I have clear the targets and built it like 10 times but still runs perfectly on xcode but the app individually isnt quite working..

Thanks in advance for any help .

I am out of ideas and i have no direction to go to as from a programming perspective the code does its work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memory management issues... be sure to remember [database release] instead of autorelease which works fine on the xcode but crashes the app in mac os